# Where can I go to find reliable Marvel reading lists?

Tags: marvel

Where can I go to find reliable Marvel reading lists?

I'm trying to put together House of M for my significant other, and I'm not sure where to start. I'll also be putting together other Marvel.. story arcs I guess I should call them(?) for him in the future. I say "for him" because it’s a gift and I'm trying to do this without letting the cat out of the bag, if you will.

I've been directed to Marvel Wikia, Wikipedia's Marvel Wiki, and Marvel's Official reading lists in the past, but with those and Google/Amazon searches it’s more information than I know anything about to even begin to process the mounds of information I'm looking at.

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to avoid simply buying the collected editions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_M#Collected_editions

Comment: @Richard No real particular reason to avoid it, just unsure where to start or how to interpret the information on the wiki pages. Are collected editions sort of standard for what I'm looking for - saying that as I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The easiest way is to just go to Amazon and search for "House of M". There are 5-6 books in the whole story arc, each telling the story from different perspectives. Unfortunately, some of them are only available in hardback on Amazon, so you may have to look elsewhere. I get a lot of my stuff from Midtown Comics as well.

Comment: @fieoreh unfortunately, this question is veering a ways off-topic for this site. Questions here should have a single "correct" answer and not be based on opinions; we can help you with reading order, and possibly your questions about reading lists, but some of the other things are likely to get your question closed. You might want to narrow your focus a bit: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Hopefully I've been able to make it more general? Thanks.

Comment: @Omegacron I've been searching Amazon myself but search results, for myself at least, tend to not paint much of a picture of all elements when searching for a particular series. :(

Comment: @fieoreh - try searching Amazon for the words "house of m tpb". That should return the collected volumes related to the story arc. The one titled just "House of M" is the main event, with "House of M: XXXXXX" telling the story from the perspective of other characters/heroes.

Comment: @Omegacron From reading the summary it seems that search results in just the main House of M issues. I guess outside of House of M, and searching amazon like that, is there anything you reference before going to Amazon to know exactly what to look for?

Comment: Nope. You typically want the paperback edition and you're looking for titles like "House of M: Spider-Man", "House of M: X-Men", etc. They really just fill in details & side stories that were left out of the main "House of M" paperback.

Answer (score 3):

Marvel has a [handy page](http://marvel.com/comics/discover/?byZone=marvel_site_zone&options[offset]=9&offset=0&options[limit]=8&options[category]=discover&options[platform]=marvel_site&options[orderBy]=rank+DESC&contentType=module_list&method=fetchAll&options%5Boffset%5D=0&totalcount=17) that has reading orders for events and for introducing yourself to various characters and creators. Unfortunately, the reading orders for events tend to be *thorough*, including all of the really tangential tie-in issues. But if you want thorough Marvel reading orders, that's where to start.

Comment: This is one that had been suggested to me multiple times...

Comment: @fieoreh I guess I'm not sure what's not clear or helpful about an ordered list of all the issues in the event. If you're buying a collected edition, it will say which issues are included. A friendly local comic book shop can help fill in any gaps.

Comment: @Keen I had to Google _tangential_, but other than that, this is a very handy answer. I've been looking for a resource like this for a while. Good job!

Comment: @Keen I've been to 4 of the local shops and was not well received when I asked questions.  
I talked to my significant other last night, in more detail, about how he put together his Civil War choices, turns out the official lists could never have helped me with it. Now he knows I'm putting something together for him, unfortunately, but at least I know where to start.
Perhaps I posed my question incorrectly, but when someone asks "What else is out there? All I've been shown are X, Y, & Z." Why suggest X,Y, or Z back to them?

Comment: @fieoreh Because sometimes X,Y, or Z *are* the best resources out there.

Comment: @fieoreh Sorry to hear you're having trouble with it. A lot of local comic shops these days are just glorified newsstands. At a GOOD comic shop, you should be able to say "I'm looking for all the 'House of M' trade paperbacks", and the guy will know exactly what you want. If nothing else, try calling Midtown Comics (www.midtowncomics.com), they have an 800 number and really know their stuff.

Comment: @phantom42 I see your point, but to just repeat X, Y, or Z without clarifying the reason does nothing.

Comment: @Omegacron Thanks, I actually purchased a couple through midtowncomics recently and it was a good process.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the cat was let out of the bag to find out more answers.

To give context and create understanding I needed to know what factors were relevant in what reading lists to follow be it individual fan created lists or official lists. In giving consideration to the person I was building/seeking a list for, it turns out I had to ask him how he built his list for Civil War. So the question was more complex and initially not phrased correctly which lead to receiving poor suggestions.

**ANSWER:** Compare fan(Google/Amazon Wish Lists/Etc) and official reading lists(those mentioned in my question), filter out for best writing/best reviews, and filter out favorite heroes if you want. Its not necessary to buy every single one to get a full understanding of the story (though I'm sure this varies by series or w/e you call them).

Comment: Thought this was relevant to my quest, once I knew I was looking for TPB's it was easier to search for lists. I came upon this one, though it hasn't been updated since 1/2011.
http://www.tradereadingorder.com/blog/2395-marvel-collected-editions-and-graphic-novels-every-tpb/